# Smart card compatible with Schlumberger (Gemalto) Cryptoflex 16K and USB reader

Tags: windows, key-management, smartcard

Another question related to previous ones [A SW system constructed with Microsoft CNG can be FIPS 140-2 Level 2 Compliant?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16216/a-sw-system-constructed-with-microsoft-cng-can-be-fips-140-2-level-2-compliant) and [About performance of Smart card for performing 3DES in a MD5 hash](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16311/about-performance-of-smard-card-for-performing-3des-in-a-md5-hash)

We need to use Smart cards compatible with old Schlumberger (now Gemalto) Cryptoflex 16K (We are not versed in Smart card providers and their functionalities).

The Smart card is used for storing keys provided by a government agency and optionally we can use it for performing the cryptographics operations, basically 3DES on a MD5 hash. We have to provide the blank Smart card to the government and they write the keys in the card (simplified). The government agency states supports Schlumberger Cryptoflex 16K or compatible Smart card. We are thinking in Gemalto but can use any other provider.

What providers and models we can use for storing the keys? Keys accessed using preferably Microsoft CNG.

What providers and models we can use for performing also the cryptographic operations (3DES)? Operations issued using preferably Microsoft CNG.

What providers and models of readers we can use? Windows Server 2008 R2, USB, contact reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your are working on some solution for the chilean interoperable electronic toll collection system. If so, check the new set of ST standards, they replaced the old key interchange using cryptoflex by a far simpler asymmetric key interchange scheme.You will not find a direct replacement for the 16k cryptoflex for this application.

Carlos Paratori

Comment: Your are right, we are working for the chilean government for a solution, not EFC, but similar one. We are looking new ST standards and new key exchange scheme using regular files instead of Smart cards are really simpler, so we are considering this approach. Thank you for the advice.